# java.time.Instant response to JavaScript date

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot server that returns me a date as follows:

```js
{
  // Some keys
  pickupDate: {
    epochSecond: 1612199331,
    nano: 428000000
  },
  // Some other keys
}
```

How can I convert that object to a JavaScript Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```js
new Date( ( 1_612_199_331 * 1_000 ) + ( 428_000_000 / 1_000_000 ) )
```

## Java

If those values come from objects in the *java.time* classes of Java 8 and later such as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), then:

- `epochSecond` represents a count of whole seconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
- `nano` represents a fractional second as a count of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), billionths of a second.

## JavaScript

While I do not know JavaScript, it seems that most implementations offer a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type. A `Date` represents a moment as seen in UTC based on a count from the same epoch reference as *java.time*.

The difference is the granularity of the fractional second. The JavaScript `Date` uses milliseconds rather the nanoseconds in *java.time*. So you will need to divide that count of nanos by 1,000,000 to get millis.

Multiply the whole seconds by a thousand to get milliseconds. And divide the count of nanos by a million to get milliseconds. Sum to get a total number of milliseconds since epoch reference. Pass to [constructor of `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

```js
const d = 
        new Date( 
          ( 1_612_199_331 * 1_000 ) 
          + 
          ( 428_000_000 / 1_000_000 ) 
        )
;
```

Generate text representing the moment stored in that `Date` using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```js
const d = new Date( ( 1_612_199_331 * 1_000 ) + ( 428_000_000 / 1_000_000 ) ) ;
console.log( d.toISOString() ) ;
```

> 2021-02-01T17:08:51.428Z

The `Z` on the end means an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. Pronounced “Zulu”.